# how to change default lambda "errorMessage" via api gateway on 200

Tags: lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am searching for the correct method to identify and change the lambda time out errorMessage using api gateway or lambda itself.

Say a script fails due to timeout and lambda is returning the following message to api gateway, with status 200

```
{
   "errorMessage": "RequestId: 6737e0a4-68af-11e7-8ab8-7fb105ccffaacc Process exited before completing request"
}
```

Is there a way to customise this with lambda? or is it better to let the api gateway do a mapping. If so can you suggest any documents as examples?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway is unable to map this to anything. It always returns status 200.